# How to cast a Fraction object to Double object?

Tags: java, casting

When I'm studying Android, I can cast an object type to other type, like this:

```
TextView txtHello = (TextView) view;
```

where `view` is defined as `View`, a reason, I think, `TextView` is a subclass of `View`. Now, I have a `Fraction` class, here is its content:

```
public class Fraction {

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction() {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 1;
    }

    public Fraction(int value) {
        numerator = value;
        denominator = 1;
    }

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) throws ArithmeticException {
        if (denominator == 0) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Denominator can not be 0!");
        }
        if (denominator < 0) {
             denominator *= -1;
             numerator *= -1;
        }
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
        this.simplify();
    }

    public double toDouble() {
        return (double) numerator / (double) denominator;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d/%d", numerator, denominator);
    }

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    private void simplify() {
        int x = getGreatestCommonDivisor(numerator, denominator);
        numerator /= x;
        denominator /= x;
    }

    private int getGreatestCommonDivisor(int x, int y) {
        x = x < 0 ? -x : x;
        y = y < 0 ? -y : y;
        if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
            return x + y;
        }
        while (x != y) {
            if (x > y) {
                x = x - y;
            } else {
                y = y - x;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

And when I create a new Fraction:

```
Fraction frac = new Fraction(2, 5);
```

Both two line are errors:

```
Double d1 = (Double) frac;
double d2 = (double) frac;
```

I know that I can convert a `Fraction` to `double` by call `toDouble` method. But I want to know how to do such as what I know in Android. I try to make `Fraction` `extends` `Double` but `Double` is a `final` class. If I create a new class as `Double`, how can I do any line code above and `d1` and `d2` is really value of `frac`?

Comment: Java doesn't allow custom casting operators in the way you're expecting.

Comment: What's wrong with `toDouble()`? What you ask for isn't possible.

Comment: This is my simple example. My question is: if I create a new class, for example, Number and make Fraction extends Number. Will this code work? `Number num = (Number) frac`

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh it would, but the cast is redundant. You can simply write `Number num = frac;` if `Fraction extends Number`.

Comment: Thanks all! Now I know that how the code `TextView txtHello = (TextView) view;` work in Android, and where I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast as they are unrelated types.

With reference types (like `Fraction` and `Double`), casting doesn't actually build a new instance of the casted-to type - `(Double) frac` simply says to the compiler "trust me, I know that this `Fraction` is really a `Double`, let me use it as one".

However, the compiler knows that `Double` isn't in the inheritance hierarchy of `Fraction`, so it knows that it is impossible for a reference to a `Fraction` to really be a `Double`, so it forbids the cast.

But you have a method to allow conversion of `Fraction` to `double`:

```
double d2 = frac.toDouble();
```

Comment: Thanks you, Andy Turner! Now I know that how the code `TextView txtHello = (TextView) view;` work in Android, and where I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

> If I create a new class as Double, how can I do any line code above and d1 and d2 is really value of frac?

In Java you can't do this without hacking the core libraries, something you shouldn't do.

What you can do is extend Number which is the parent of Double.

```
Number num = new Fraction(2, 3); // if Fraction extends Number
Number d = 1.33;
```

Comment: Thanks you, Peter Lawrey! Now I know that how the code `TextView txtHello = (TextView) view;` work in Android, and where I'm wrong!